# Curl Request Node JS and max post size

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to send data from curl request to PHP, I use curl.request, but when my data size exceed 128KO, i have no data received :

**Code**

```
var a = JSON.stringfy(myVar);
curl.request({

    url : "https://www.test.com/test/test.php",
    method : 'POST',
    data : a,

}, function(err, stdout, body) {

    res.send(stdout);

});
```

How to increase the max post data size.

Thank you.

Comment: what's the object you are using in this `curl` ?

Comment: An object like this : {key1: "val1", key2 : "val2"}

Comment: i mean the module you are using ?

Comment: Are you sure the PHP server [isn't limiting the size of uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)?